# Saving file in IIS hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, .net-4.0, save

#### Problem

When saving an image in the server using an *absolute* file name (eg. `C:/tinkiwinki/dipsy.lala`) with the [`System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148.aspx) method in a WCF Service hosted in IIS, it doesn't save the image and doesn't even throw an exception.

#### Background

We have a helper class and it has a `SaveJpeg` method:

```
public class Tools
{
    public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img, int quality)
    {
        if (quality < 0 || quality > 100)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Quality must be between 0 and 100.");

        EncoderParameter qualityParam =
            new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);

        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

        img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
    }
}
```

We use it in a WCF `OperationContract` method like this:

```
string destDirectory = ServerDataFilePath.ImagesPath + @"\" + uploadID.ToString();
if (!Directory.Exists(destDirectory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirectory);
Tools.SaveJpeg(destDirectory + @"\" + fileName, img, 50);
```

The static `ServerDataFilePath.ImagesPath` is defined like this:

```
public class ServerDataFilePath
{
    public static string ImagesPath{ get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ImagesPath"].ConnectionString; } }
}
```

Where it retrieves the `ConnectionString` from the *Web.config* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="ImagesPath" connectionString="C:\testServerImagesPath\"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

#### Question

It works perfectly when we run it locally but when we deploy it in our test server using IIS, it doesn't save the images and doesn't throw any exceptions. Why was it like this?

#### Some Constraints

Code is in C#, framework 4, build in Visual Studio 2010 Professional. The service is deployed in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 in IIS, service type is WCF in .NET 4.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this image uploaded from client? if yes are you streaming the file correctly?

Comment: @BrijeshMishra Yes, we actually use `byte[]` to retrieve images and convert it to `Image`. We already test that locally and it works perfectly, the problem now is the saving of images when we deploy the service in IIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very probably the account that your Web app is running under on IIS does not have write privileges on the `C:\tinkiwinki` folder.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the `C:\tinkiwinki` folder doesn't exist yet. I expect the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` method to create that for me, or it isn't? I'll check on the privileges of our IIS.

Comment: If the account that your app runs under does not have write privileges to C:, it won't be able to create that directory either.

Comment: How can I add the IIS in the security privileges of our drive? Is there an object name for the IIS service?

Comment: You need to figure out under which account your app runs. This will be the account that runs the application pool that your app is defined in. To find out more, have a look at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities.